# How to perform an emergency shutdown without sudo?

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, shutdown, root

### The Problem

Am trying allow a specific user, who is in the group `sudo`, to perform an emergency shutdown using the following code:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Note, this is **without** using the command `sudo`!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that both files, owned by `root:root`, refuse to allow any permission or owner changes, even by the `root` user.

### Theoretical Scenario

A hacker compromises a system, which is usually left to run without supervision, and gained permissions to read confidential data. Rather than allowing the hacker to continue, an automated script powers off the machine (assume that the hack has been detected).

While not my exact use case, it is similar enough.

### What I Have Tried

- Creating a bash script to perform the above 2 lines of code, giving
  it `root:sudo` owners, and adding a line to `visudo` to allow the
  specific user to run the task without needing to enter the password.
- Attempted to change the owner of the 2 files to `root:sudo`.
- Attempted to change the permissions of the 2 files such that the
  group `root` could write to them.

The idea is to not "bake in" the password for `sudo`, which will allow me to change is regularly without forgetting to modify other files (or to have the process which turns off the computer running with `root` privileges). Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is to change your lines into something like this in your script:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq > /dev/null
echo o | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger > /dev/null
```

And give the specific user access to run `tee` command with these arguments without the need of entering password, something like:

```
username ALL=(root:root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

Remember that it's not possible to redirect an string into a file which needs a specific permission using `>`, it means something like:

```
sudo echo hi > file
echo hi sudo >  file
```

is not going to work.

At the same time you can't simply change the owner of these files, cause `/proc` is a virtual file system managed by Kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Works like a charm. Did not know about the limitation with echo, so thanks for explaining that to me as well =)